# Can't parse serialized form data from ajax request to php array

Tags: php, ajax, pjax

I am trying to parse the data sent from the `$.pjax` request, to php array.
I tried with `parse_str` but `NULL` is returned. Also with `unserialize()` the result was:
`unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 210 bytes`
What is the right way to do it ? My code looks like:

```
function loadNewProducts() {
    $.pjax.defaults.timeout = false
    $.pjax({
        url: location.href.split('?')[0],
        data: {
            form: $("#dynamic-form-new-products").serialize()
        },
        container: "#new_products"
    })
}
```

The `$_GET['form']` parameter looks like:

```
string(210) "_csrf-backend=BaUAnGywhydYkWrYU6tBNwyju5ofhIwAw0AO60naP4NP_DHzCIbzHhPnL5Ef7wZSXtXZ2F72uzmkbT6gBZFo1g%3D%3D&NewProduct%5B0%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=2&NewProduct%5B0%5D%5Bstart_date%5D=&NewProduct%5B0%5D%5Bend_date%5D="
```

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using the $output parameter then you could be seeing this issue because of the leading underscore not being valid as the start of a PHP variable identifier. Without $output this would result in a variable called `$_csrf-backend` which isn't allowed. I can't test it myself but the following usage is recommended on PHP.net:

```
parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz
```

[Example Source](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#refsect1-function.parse-str-examples)

Another thing I would recommend is trying to parse the whole query string `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: Love it, I'm using Yii2 and passing 2 serialized forms through ajax as an array both with csrf tokens that start with an underscore so the unserialize() function won't work, parse_str() works perfectly!